# How to use a System Environment Variable in an Environment Variable in Vercel

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, vercel

I'm deploying a NextJs project with the help of Vercel.
I am using [Kinde](https://kinde.com/) for the authentication.

Kinde requires to have the following environment variable:

```
KINDE_SITE_URL:http://localhost:300 // This is the value in my local .env file
```

And then I have the following in my Vercel environment variables:

```
KINDE_SITE_URL:https://<project-name>.vercel.app // This is the deployed url of the main branch
```

So far so good, it is working for the deployed version of my app (on branch main).

Vercel provide a cool preview feature: whenever I create a Pull request on Github, it creates a preview deployment from this branch, with the following url:

```
https://<project-name>-<unique-hash>-<scope-slug>.vercel.app
```

The problem is that the URL can't be hardoded, as it is dependent on the git branch.
In the [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables/system-environment-variables), I red that there is the VERCEL_URL System Environment Variable, that contains exactly the url of the deployed version.

So my question is: how can I insert this value in to the other environment variable?

I would like something like this:

```
KINDE_SITE_URL=${VERCEL_URL}
```

I want to add that is it not code related, as I am not using the `KINDE_SITE_UR`L directly in the code, it is used by a third party library.
So this variable should be set through the Vercel UI (if possible), otherwise I can't test the authentication during the preview deployment, only on the final deployment on the main branch (because it has the correct hardcoded url as environment variable)

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a way, but it doesn't work through the Vercel UI.
In a .env.production file, I have the following :

```
KINDE_SITE_URL=https://$VERCEL_URL
```